# Both IE and Chrome (dev tool) dont show any error(s), then what?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010, slide

Is the $(".slides_container").append(liHtml) correctly syntaxed? No 1 (browser client) is complaining.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_layouts/jquery/global.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/jquery/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>


<script>
        $(function(){
            $('#slides').slides({
                preload: true,
                preloadImage: '_layouts/jquery/loading.gif',
                play: 5000,
                pause: 2500,
                hoverPause: true,
                animationStart: function(current){
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:-50
                    },100);
                    if (window.console && console.log) {
                        // example return of current slide number
                        console.log('animationStart on slide: ', current);
                    };
                },
                animationComplete: function(current){
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:0
                    },200);
                    if (window.console && console.log) {
                        // example return of current slide number
                        console.log('animationComplete on slide: ', current);
                    };
                },
                slidesLoaded: function() {
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:0
                    },200);
                }
            });
        });
</script>

<div id="container">    
    <div id="slides">
        <div class="slides_container"></div>
        <a href="#" class="prev"><img src="_layouts/jquery/arrow-prev.png" width="24" height="43" alt="Arrow Prev"></a>
        <a href="#" class="next"><img src="_layouts/jquery/arrow-next.png" width="24" height="43" alt="Arrow Next"></a>
    </div>
    <img src="_layouts/jquery/example-frame.png" width="739" height="341" alt="Example Frame" id="frame">
</div>      

<script>

  function GetAllImages()
    {
       $("#slideshowPicturePlaceholder").css("display", "block");
       var soapEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soapenv:Body><GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>";
       soapEnv += "<listName>Splash Image Rotator</listName>";
       soapEnv += "<query><Query><Where><Eq> <FieldRef Name='Active'/> <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value> </Eq> </Where><OrderBy Override='TRUE'><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query></query>";
       soapEnv += "<viewFields><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='ows_FileLeafRef'/><FieldRef Name='NewsLink'/></ViewFields></viewFields><rowLimit></rowLimit>";      
       soapEnv += "</GetListItems></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";

       var port = window.location.port;
       if (port.length <= 0)
       port = "";
       else
       port = ":" + port;
       var webservice = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + port + L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";

       $.ajax(
       {
          url : webservice,
          type : "POST",
          dataType : "xml",
          data : soapEnv,
          complete : processQueryResults,
          contentType : "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
          error : function (xhr)
          {
             alert('Error!  Status = ' + xhr.status);
          }
       });   
    }
    function processQueryResults(xData, status)
    {
       var port = window.location.port;
       if (port.length <= 0)
       port = "";
       else
       port = ":" + port;

       var imageURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + port + L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/Splash Image Rotator/";           
       $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function ()
       {
          var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");          
          var imageLink = imageURL + $(this).attr("ows_FileLeafRef").substring($(this).attr("ows_FileLeafRef").indexOf('#') + 1);         
          var itemLink = $(this).attr("ows_NewsLink");
          var liHtml = "<div class='slide'><a href='"+itemLink+"' target='_blank' border='0'><img width='420' height='220'  src='" + imageLink +"'/></a>" + "<div class='caption' style=\"bottom:'0'\"><p>" + title + "</p></div></div>";

        $(".slides_container").append(liHtml);      
        });

    }             
GetAllImages();

</script>
```

Comment: Mike a couple of suggestions. Cut down all this code to just the code you want us to look at - this is way too much for a simple jquery append syntax question. Also, edit your title so it's clear that you are actually interested in asking about JQuery .append(). Last, what browser is your client using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check your markup (a bit edited) against the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <title>asdf</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='slide'><a href='asdf' target='_blank' border='0'><img width='420' height='220'  src='asdf'/></a><div class='caption' style='bottom:0'><p>asdf</p></div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This gives the following errors:

- an anchor does not have a border attribute. Did you mean to style it like `<a style="border:0;">`?
- an image should have an alt tag

So yes, your markup at liHtml is invalid, but easy to fix.